# How to disable css for particular inner div tag in content page of nested master's page?

Tags: css

i have a problem to override the css in content page div tag .

I'm using nested masters.So in both master pages i used so many div tags with same css theme.

But i want to omit css style for one particular div tag in content page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "nested masters", "div tags" and "css themes" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've defined styles to div { ... } in your CSS, then you can't simply 'disable' them on a new div unless you explicitly redefine them to the default. If all you div styles are declared via class or id attributes, then using a bare div will have this same effect.

Example, bad CSS. *This can't be overridden without explicitly giving your target div a class or id and redefining font-size.*

```
div { font-size: 23em; }
```

Example, better CSS. *If you define all your div CSS with classes and ID's then when you want default styling just use a unclassed, un-ID'ed div.*

```
div.reallyBig { font-size: 23em; }
```

Without seeing your original markup its hard to be much more specific. You may need to reassign styles / classes / id's for your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the div an ID and a style of its own using an id selector (#). You can't disable CSS for a specific instance of a tag.

Comment: can u give me the snippet code,because i will try.

Thanks for ur response.